# Mix action and slug in zend framework 2 route

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, slug

I have this route configuration:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'blog' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/blog',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Blog',
                    'action' => 'list',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'create' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/create',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'create',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ),
                'view' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:slug]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'slug' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'view',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

the intent is to use the following url:

1. /blog -> for listing all blog posts
2. /blog/create -> for create new post
3. /blog/this-is-the-post-title for the view of one post

the route configuration works for points 1 and 3 but not for number two (I get "The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request."), can someone explain me why? and which is the correct configuration?

Comment: put create route definition after view, i think the route matches the last route it finds

Answer (score 1):

The `Router` will return the last route definition that it can find in a set of same level child routes.

for child routes in the same level put `Segment` routes definition before `Literals`.